# Unable to verify OpenSSL C++ Signature in C#

Tags: c#, c++, openssl, cryptography, rsa

I have a keypair generated using openSSL in C++ which i am using to sign a message for authentication over a C# server which strictly uses RSACryptoServiceProvider(no BouncyCastle etc.). I have used PKCS#1 SHA256 to generate signature.The signature is then transported in hexadecimal form along with the public key. The problem is the signature fails to verify on the server.
I have tried removing the header which says "-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----" and so. But no results yet.The c++ code for generating keypair and signature is:

```
RSA             *keypair = NULL;
bne = BN_new();
int  ret = 0;
ret = BN_set_word(bne, ea);
keypair = RSA_new();    
RSA_generate_key_ex(keypair , 2048, bne, NULL);
SHA256((unsigned char*)msg, strlen(msg) + 1, hash);
RSA_sign(NID_sha256, hash, SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH, sign,&signLen, keypair);
```

I have collected the public key in a character buffer using BIO and converted the signature data to hex string for transporting to c#. I however tried to replicate the server by writing a sample form application and the signature and public key which are verified on c++,i have passed them hardcoded as inputs to c# sample.But they also fail.
Can anyone help me out what are the possible reasons or areas of fallacy?

```
 RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
 RSA.ImportParameters(rsParam);
 UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
 byte[] datax = encoding.GetBytes(data);
 byte[] sigx = encoding.GetBytes(sig);
 SHA256Managed sha256 = new SHA256Managed();
 byte[] hash = sha256.ComputeHash(datax);
 iRes= RSA.VerifyHash(hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256"), sigx);
```

The 'data' is passed and also the 'sig' which is a hard-coded value,'rsParam have been created using hard-coded public key used to generate 'sig'. The code for conversion of public key to rsParam is:

```
pubkey = Convert.FromBase64String(pemString);
RSAParameters rsParam = RSA.ExportParameters(false);
rsParam .Modulus = pubkey;
RSA.ImportParameters(rsParam );
```

I wrote this code just to know how the basic C# cryptography system works,so that it can be of some help to research on the actual issue.

Comment: You should share how you're doing the validation, including with hard-coded inputs.

Comment: `SHA256((unsigned char*)msg, strlen(msg) + 1, hash);` - C# uses UTF-16 by default, so you are going to have problems if you blindly cut-over to C#. You really need to show your code.

Comment: I dont have the actual server code,if i had it i would have made out what the area of fallacy is,i have written a basic c# code after looking into posts over the web as c# is not my expertise,i dont know how similar it would be to the actual server code,however i am sharing what i have written in c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer,instead of signing with RSA_Sign,i used RSA_private_encrypt with RSA_PKCS1_PADDING as a parameter to sign the SHA256 hash and the signature got verified on the server end,the server code as i mentioned earlier was not transparent to me so this was just a brute-force approach and it worked. The sample C# code i had written still doesnt verify it but it is not of any concern to me as for now.